# VGA DDC voltage

Tags: i2c, level-shifting, vga

While designing a pcb with a VGA output, I came across the DDC pins on the connector. I'd like to use that protocol to retrieve data from the monitor.

After searching on the internet, I found that the DDC I2C signals are 5V, but isn't I2C open drain ?
So to interface it with a 3v3 device, couldn't I have 3v3 pull-ups on SDA and SCL instead of using a level shifter ?

Answer (score 1):

The DDC I2C interface is 5 V, yes. And indeed, the I2C uses open collector so one could potentially pull up to some other voltage.

Although, you can not be sure that the 5 V device in the display would recognize 3.3 V as logic high level.

But you could easily implement level shifters using a single MOSFET per data line, like this:
[image]

Comment: Ok I didn't know if the monitor had pull-ups already. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The DDC specification is freely available for download so you can read the requirements there.

In short, your board is the DDC host and the open-drain I2C interface must have the specified strong pull-ups to 5V. 3.3V is not within the specs.

It is up to your MCU if it can handle 5V on IO pins directly like some MCUs do, or if it does not then you need a level shifter between 3.3V MCU and 5V DDC bus.